# String limit of chars

Tags: java, string, sockets

I'm developing an application that sends a String via socket, but I have not set a limit to the String dimension.
Is there a limit of a String size in chars or bytes in java?
And what about send a very large String (millions of chars) via socket? Is there a limit?

Comment: Answer might have here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544924/maximum-size-of-data-that-can-be-fetched-from-a-client-socket-using-socketchanne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of chars in a string is determined by the max size of an array in Java. That being Integer.MAX_VALUE (2,147,483,647). You will most likely run out of RAM before you hit that limit.

There is no limit to the number of chars that can be sent through a Socket.

If the structure of your data allows for it you might be served by working with a streaming API. e.g. if you string is coming out of a DB or from disk start streaming it down the socket as your read it into memory. That way you don't have to hold the entire string in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The max size of a string is the max number of characters the *underlying char array can accept* which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum length of an String is `Integer.MAX_INT = 2 147 483 647`. This is assuming you have enough memory to hold a `String` of that size, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a String of length Integer.MAX_VALUE (always 2147483647 (2^31 - 1) by the Java specification, the maximum size of an array, which the String class uses for internal storage) or half your maximum heap size (since each character is two bytes), whichever is smaller.

[Source](https://www.google.com.bd/?gws_rd=ssl#q=String%20size%20limit%20in%20java)